# AWS DMS CDC - Only capture changed values not entire record? (Source RDS MySQL)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-dms

I have a DMS CDC task set (change data capture) from a MySQL database to stream to a Kinesis stream which a Lambda is connected to.

I was hoping to ultimately receive only the value that has changed and not on entire dump of the row, this way I know what column is being changed (at the moment it's impossible to decipher this without setting up another system to track changes myself).

Example, with the following mapping rule:

```
     {
        "rule-type": "selection",
        "rule-id": "1",
        "rule-name": "1",
        "object-locator": {
            "schema-name": "my-schema",
            "table-name": "product"
        },
        "rule-action": "include",
        "filters": []
    },
```

and if I changed the name property of a record on the product table, I would hope to recieve a record like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "newValue"
    },
    "metadata": {
        "timestamp": "2021-07-26T06:47:15.762584Z",
        "record-type": "data",
        "operation": "update",
        "partition-key-type": "schema-table",
        "schema-name": "my-schema",
        "table-name": "product",
        "transaction-id": 8633730840
    }
}
```

However what I actually recieve is something like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "newValue",
        "id": "unchangedId",
        "quantity": "unchangedQuantity",
        "otherProperty": "unchangedValue"
    },
    "metadata": {
        "timestamp": "2021-07-26T06:47:15.762584Z",
        "record-type": "data",
        "operation": "update",
        "partition-key-type": "schema-table",
        "schema-name": "my-schema",
        "table-name": "product",
        "transaction-id": 8633730840
    }
}
```

As you can see when receiving this, it's impossible to decipher what property has changed without setting up additional systems to track this.

I've found another [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64912173/aws-dms-with-cdc-the-update-records-only-include-the-updated-field-how-to-incl) where someone is posting an issue because their CDC is doing **what I want mine to do**. Can anyone point me into the right direction to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer after digging into AWS documentation some more.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Kinesis.html#CHAP_Target.Kinesis.BeforeImage

> Different source database engines provide different amounts of
> information for a before image:
>
> - Oracle provides updates to columns only if they change.
> - PostgreSQL provides only data for columns that are part of the primary
>   key (changed or not).
> - MySQL generally provides data for all columns (changed or not).

I used the [BeforeImageSettings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Kinesis.html#CHAP_Target.Kinesis.BeforeImage) on the task setting to include the original data with payloads.

```
"BeforeImageSettings": {
    "EnableBeforeImage": true,
    "FieldName": "before-image",
    "ColumnFilter": "all"
}
```

While this still gives me the whole record, it give me enough data to work out what's changed without additional systems.

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "newValue",
        "id": "unchangedId",
        "quantity": "unchangedQuantity",
        "otherProperty": "unchangedValue"
    },
    "before-image": {
        "name": "oldValue",
        "id": "unchangedId",
        "quantity": "unchangedQuantity",
        "otherProperty": "unchangedValue"
    },
    "metadata": {
        "timestamp": "2021-07-26T06:47:15.762584Z",
        "record-type": "data",
        "operation": "update",
        "partition-key-type": "schema-table",
        "schema-name": "my-schema",
        "table-name": "product",
        "transaction-id": 8633730840
    }
}
```